# How to increase touch area control points on mobile device ( not increase display size of control points ) in fabricjs?

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs, gesture, fabricjs2

How to increase touch area of control points on mobile device with FabricJS? Because on mobile they are too small for smooth interactive with. But not change size of control points ( for nice view ).

Here is my code:
How to increase interactive of control points = view control points size x 2 ?

```js
var canvasObject = document.getElementById("editorCanvas");
  // set canvas equal size with div
  $(canvasObject).width($("#canvasContainer").width());
  $(canvasObject).height($("#canvasContainer").height());

  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('editorCanvas', {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    selectionLineWidth: 2,
    width: $("#canvasContainer").width(),
    height: $("#canvasContainer").height()
  });

  // test customize control points
  var rect = new fabric.Rect({
   left: 30,
   top: 30,
   fill: 'red',
   width: 150,
   height: 150
  });
    
    canvas.add(rect);
    
    rect.set({
   transparentCorners: false,
   cornerColor: 'white',
   cornerStrokeColor: 'rgba(14,19,24,.15)',
   borderColor: 'rgba(41,198,203,1)',
   selectionLineWidth: 8,
   cornerSize: 12,
   cornerStyle: 'circle',
  });
```

```css
#canvasContainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: gray;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.3.2/fabric.js"></script>

<div id="canvasContainer">
  <canvas id="editorCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Please show me the way to resolve this problem.

By the way: ( on mobile device ) is there any way to allow drag object only object is selected before?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can change using `cornerSize`

Comment: Hi @Durga, I only want to increase interactive zone ( this zone is invisible with user ), but not change visible control point size. Is there any way to implement it ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to override `_setCornerCoords` method of object and change the value of `cornerHypotenuse`.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvasObject = document.getElementById("editorCanvas");
// set canvas equal size with div
$(canvasObject).width($("#canvasContainer").width());
$(canvasObject).height($("#canvasContainer").height());

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('editorCanvas', {
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  selectionLineWidth: 2,
  width: $("#canvasContainer").width(),
  height: $("#canvasContainer").height()
});

// test customize control points
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 30,
  top: 30,
  fill: 'red',
  width: 150,
  height: 150
});

canvas.add(rect);

rect.set({
  transparentCorners: false,
  cornerColor: 'white',
  cornerStrokeColor: 'rgba(14,19,24,.15)',
  borderColor: 'rgba(41,198,203,1)',
  selectionLineWidth: 8,
  cornerSize: 5,
  cornerStyle: 'circle'
});
rect._setCornerCoords = function() {
  var coords = this.oCoords,
    newTheta = fabric.util.degreesToRadians(45 - this.angle),
    cornerHypotenuse = this.cornerSize * 2 * 0.707106,
    cosHalfOffset = cornerHypotenuse * fabric.util.cos(newTheta),
    sinHalfOffset = cornerHypotenuse * fabric.util.sin(newTheta),
    x, y;

  for (var point in coords) {
    x = coords[point].x;
    y = coords[point].y;
    coords[point].corner = {
      tl: {
        x: x - sinHalfOffset,
        y: y - cosHalfOffset
      },
      tr: {
        x: x + cosHalfOffset,
        y: y - sinHalfOffset
      },
      bl: {
        x: x - cosHalfOffset,
        y: y + sinHalfOffset
      },
      br: {
        x: x + sinHalfOffset,
        y: y + cosHalfOffset
      }
    };
  }
}
```

```css
#canvasContainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: gray;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.3.2/fabric.js"></script>

<div id="canvasContainer">
  <canvas id="editorCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```